# How to validate against a simple username and password in a login page made using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a school/uni-project and is trying to:

1) make a class called "bruker" (Norwegian for "user") that includes a simple username and password. The code for this class is stored in the "App-Code --> Bruker.cs".

2) create a simple login-page that checks against this username and password (for now I am just testing using the password, not the username). The file for the login-page is called InnUtlogging.aspx.

The problem is that I am not able to get my if-else statement (that I use to validate the password) to check against the password-variable (that I have tried to create by attempting to create an "object" based on the "bruker/user class" that I also have tried to make ).

The relevant code is this:

From App_Code --> Bruker.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Bruker
/// </summary>
public class Bruker
{
    public String Brukernavn;
    public String Passord;



    public Bruker() //The "constructor"
    {
        Brukernavn = "brukernavn";
        Passord = "passord";


    }
}
```

From InnUtlogging.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class InnUtlogging : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Bruker bruker1 = new Bruker();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lblPassord.Text == Passord.Text)
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://localhost:64927/KunstnerAdmin.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Innlogging feilet.";
        }
    }
}
```

A zip-file of my attempt can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6L5wBJr-eDseDhLQXNOZnFTb28/view?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Jørgen

Comment: looks like your comparing the value of a label to the value of a textbox, where do you reference your bruker object?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thanks. 

I also found another way of bringing about approximately the same functionality I wanted (from chp 19: Security Fundamentals in the book Beginning .ASP 4.5 in C# by Matthew MacDonald.)

Comment: What is the solution? Adding "Solved" to the question's title does not help other people. This is a Question and Answer site where answers are wanted to help other people in the future. Please provide an answer or this question is likely to be deleted.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your title, that's not how we do it.  Either let @MikeD add an answer below, or add one yourself with details of the solution. Then select it as correct after the required waiting period.

Comment: Aha. Sorry, I am new to Stackoverflow. I have written the proper answer now, and will mark it as correct after the waiting period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using a "label" to compare with (what I intended to be) the password-variable. I should have used a "textbox", not a "label".

I'm not actually sure if the password-variable works as I intended, as I found another way of doing it that seems to work fine for me. The method I am now using is described in  "Chp 19: Security Fundamentals" in the book "Beginning .ASP 4.5 in C#" by Matthew MacDonald (under the headlines "Forms authentication" and "the Login Page"). It involves using the built-in classes, instead of trying to create a new class and object to store the username and password.

Here's the relevant code from the InnUtlogging.aspx.cs using the new method:

```
public partial class InnUtlogging : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ( textNavn.Text == "brukernavn" && textPassord.Text == "passord")
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(
                textNavn.Text, false);
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Innlogging feilet."; //means "login failed".
        }
    }
}
```

I also had to change the Web.config file. Here the relevant excerpt:

```
  <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="KunstCookie"
               loginUrl="InnUtlogging.aspx"
               defaultUrl="SalgsOversiktAdmin.aspx"
               protection="All"
               timeout="30" path="/" />
      </authentication>

      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
```